# How do I display a value for a field of an object that is within an object?

Tags: c#, html, .net

I don't really know the right words to ask the question that I need which means that I'm not really getting anything from google, so I'm just going to create a simple example. If you can answer my question or just point me in the direction of what I need to search, that would be great.

Say I have these classes:

```
 public class Teacher
{
    public int teacherID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string courseName { get; set; }
    public int? teacherID { get; set; }
    public Teacher teacher { get; set; }
}

public class schoolDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

How do I display in HTML the teacher's name when displaying the course. For example when I have what is below for the view, the teacher's name is blank. What do I need to change so that the teacher's name for the course is displayed?

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.teacher.Name)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.teacher.Name)
        </td>
   </tr>
}
```

This is the configuration that I've rewritten about 30 times:

```
 protected override void Seed(school.Models.schoolDBContext context)
        {
            context.Courses.AddOrUpdate(i => i.ID,
                new Course
                {
                    courseName = "Math",
                    teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 1, name = "Ms. Brooks" },
                    teacherID = 1
                },
                 new Course
                {
                    courseName = "Science",
                    teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 2, name = "Ms. James" },
                    teacherID = 2
                },
                 new Course
                {
                    courseName = "History",
                    teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 3, name = "Ms. Davidson" },
                    teacherID = 3
                }
           );
        }
```

The page looks like this.
[image]

But if I do this for the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var _coursesList = new List<Course>();
            _coursesList.Add(new Course { ID = 1, courseName = "English", teacherID = 1, teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 1, name = "Mrs. Thomas" } });
            _coursesList.Add(new Course { ID = 2, courseName = "History", teacherID = 2, teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 2, name = "Ms. Jones" } });
            _coursesList.Add(new Course { ID = 3, courseName = "Math", teacherID = 2, teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 2, name = "Ms. Fisher" } });

            return View(_coursesList);

           // return View(db.Courses.ToList());
        }
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure model.Teacher.Name has a value? You can check in the controller before you return the view while debugging.

Comment: I'm testing it with a local database that I've seeded the data for. Even though it shows a value in the database, it doesn't seem to be coming through for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have fill the Model object

Ex:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var _courselst = new List<Course>();
        _courselst.Add(new Course { CourseID = 1, Name = "IT", Teacher = new Teacher { Name = "Scot", TeacherID = 1 } });
        _courselst.Add(new Course { CourseID = 2, Name = "ACC", Teacher = new Teacher { Name = "Manj", TeacherID = 2 } });
        _courselst.Add(new Course { CourseID = 3, Name = "MATHS", Teacher = new Teacher { Name = "Demion", TeacherID = 3 } });

        return View(_courselst);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to check that the rest of my code is working. It works when I hard code it like this, so there must be a problem with the way that I have seeded the data. I've tried over twenty different ways to do it too, and spent the entire day on it yesterday, but I can't figure out why the data isn't coming through.

Comment: if you can post rest of model binder code i might check for it

Comment: Did I post enough?

Comment: I just notice something strange in Teacher class 'name' but in View you bind 'Name'. can you please have a look on that. I am not sure about it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure id I understand your question, but i think you can create a read only property, like that:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public String TeacherName 
    { 
        get {
            return Teacher?.Name ?? Name
        }
    }
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeacherName)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Teacher.Name)
        </td>
   </tr>
}
```